# Clear the CLR memory

Tags: memory, clr

Im running into a problem where the tool im using for development (a simulator tool) keeps throwing OutofMemoryException's, I know its not my app, because no matter what project im running, it happens.

The only fix I have for it so far is to restart my PC, is there a way to flush/clear the CLR runtime so I dont have to restart my PC each time it happens?

Comment: Im at my wits end here... I must figure out what the hell is happening, I cant afford to keep on restarting my PC

Comment: Can I increase my CLR memory somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Each process that runs managed code starts up a separate copy of the CLR runtime - and when any kind of process is terminated, the memory it consumed is reclaimed into the general pool.

There is nothing shared to "flush" or "clear".

Is it possible that your simulator tool isn't crashing "all the way" - that the process is sticking around in a faulted state?

Comment: Possibly, but I cannot see any processes that look suspicious at the moment. I really have no idea :(

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a 3rd party tool. So I'd be filing a bug request with them.

But as others have said, the issue will be contained within an operating system process. Using task manager, you should be able to identify the offending process and kill it. That will reclaim the memory and wipe the slate clean. You'll then have to restart your simulation.

If this problem is preventing you from completing your simulation, then I'd file an urgent (but not angry) bug request.

Comment: Thats just the thing, I dont see any tasks that are taking up that much memory. But dont worry I will be raising a bug fix! :)

Comment: OoME can be caused by things other than using lots of memory. I once got an OoME because I forgot to dispose of Bitmap objects, I exhausted the supply of GDI handles.

Answer (score 0):

OutOfMemoryExceptions don't necessarily indicate a problem with the runtime.  Any time your system runs out of memory, regardless of what's consuming it, this can happen.

Look at the process list in the task manager and see what's consuming the most memory.

Comment: I see, well, looking at my task manager, Im only using 1.68GB of memory and the PC has 4GB available to it. So I dont think that its the physical resources thats the problem

Comment: Ok.  It could be that the GC heap is fragmented.  You could try using the DumpHeap command in the SOS Debugging Extension (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764%28VS.80%29.aspx).  If you see a large percentage of "Free" slots, you've got fragmentation.

Comment: You have to figure out what's causing the fragmentation and fix it.  This is in no way an easy task.  Here's an article that goes into great detail explaining it: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1409801&seqNum=1

I'm sorry I don't have a simple answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

A x86/32-bit user-mode process on Windows only has an addressable virtual memory space of 2GB.  An x64/64-bit process has 16TB of addressable virtual memory. You did not say if your process was 32 or 64 bit - but I'll assume 32-bit.  Once a 32-bit process starts to venture into the 1.5+ GB area of Virtual or Committed Memory you are playing with fire and it is a matter of time before the app crashes.  There is no hard and fast number on when it will crash since every app is different.

So let's talk about the "2GB" of addressable space...the memory that is used by your *application* does NOT have access to all of the 2GB of memory. There is overhead used by lots of pieces that the CLR needs to run an application:

1. The 8 different heaps for a .NET app - see my answer to [.NET process memory usage = 5x CLR Heap Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121943/net-process-memory-usage-5x-clr-heap-memory/12075877#12075877)
2. Kernel overhead for running the user-mode process
3. Threads
4. etc.

So you can have gigs of memory available on your system, but an app can easily crash if it is x86 and approaching the limit described above.

I have posted quite a bit of answers and info on CLR memory here on StackOverflow describing how a lot of this works.  Look for my name and check out some of the other answers. It might help clear things up a little.

HTH