# .NET process memory usage = 5x CLR Heap Memory?

Tags: .net, memory, process, clr, heap-memory

I'm trying to tackle down some memory usage issues. Overall my application collects a few data values and visualizes them using a C1 WPF charts and datagrids finally putting everything into PDF reports.

Profiling my process using YourKit I'm faced with the situation, that the CLR heap size is ~120MB (which is all fine) while the process memory size is ~580MB. This is nearly 5 times the memory consumption of my actual CLR heap size. My CLR peak size was 220MB vs. 710MB process memory allocation.

I'm well aware that there is some overhead required on my object heap, stacks and so on. In Java JVMs the typical factor I'm used to was around ~1.5x.

How can this excessive memory overhead be explained? Is the processs just allocating free spare heap space? If yes, does this explain the 710MB vs. 220MB?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A couple of additional notes here. Though I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "CLR Heap Size".
Depending on the .NET Runtime you're using, there are 8 or 9 different heaps that the CLR uses - so the memory you see in the Heap Size vs. VM size accounts for *some* of the difference:

1. Loader Heap: contains CLR structures and the type system
2. High Frequency Heap: statics, MethodTables, FieldDescs, interface map
3. Low Frequency Heap: EEClass, ClassLoader and lookup tables
4. Stub Heap: stubs for CAS, COM wrappers, P/Invoke
5. Large Object Heap: memory allocations that require more than 85k bytes
6. GC Heap: user allocated heap memory private to the app
7. JIT Code Heap: memory allocated by mscoreee (Execution Engine) and the JIT compiler for managed code
8. Process/Base Heap: interop/unmanaged allocations, native memory, etc
9. **added in .NET 5**: [Pinned Object Heap (POH)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/internals-of-the-poh/)

Two other items which can cause excessive memory usage are memory fragmentation (mostly occurs on the LOH or large object heap) or a high number of Threads.

There are many causes for memory fragmentation and the best way to rule this out is to use WinDbg to analyze the segment sizes for each segment on the GC Heap.

As far as a high number of threads, you have either 1MB (for x86 process) or 4MB (for x64 process) of stack space allocated for each thread that your app uses. This memory is placed in the Process/Base Heap. Therefore if you have 100 threads, you can have up to additional 100MB/400MB of memory usage.

HTH

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable and extensive notes esp. regarding the anatomy and potential issues regarding .NET memory allocation. In my case it finally turned out to be the C1 graph component which used large blocks memory via GDI+. As a Java expert I was totally puzzled not to be able to see this with .NET memory profiler tools. Finally we had to workaround/solve this issue by restricting the usage of those C1 graph components.

Comment: Glad to help. I've had to debug many memory dumps with WinDbg which has taught me quite a bit. When working with 3rd party components I'd keep an eye on 2 things: first, make sure they are being disposed of and secondly keep an eye on the number of Handles that your app is using. This can easily be done by using either TaskManager (make sure the Handles col is visible) or the SysInternals ProcessExplorer. Usually, you would use a 'using()' statement to ensure the components are disposed of timely. However I'm not familiar with WPF so this might already be taken care of by the framework.

Comment: Ben, how did you figure out the GDI+ was consuming the memory?

Answer (score 3):

If the total size of the managed heaps is significantly smaller than the private bytes used by your application it's likely that you're allocating unmanaged memory and (possibly) not disposing of it properly. Graphic objects, streams and other objects that implement IDisposable need to have their `Dispose()` method called before they go out of scope or be placed with in a `using(){}` statement so that any unmanaged resources get cleaned up. Using a tool like ANTS Memory Profiler can show you how your memory is being allocated and which objects implement IDisposable.

Comment: Thank you Dan! This is exactly the pointer I was missing. Probably ANTS probably won't help here either, (I was already using YourKit) as it cannot track unmanaged memory leaks. Currently I'm trying to tackle down my issue using DebugDiag 1.2

Comment: I'm not familiar with DebugDiag, but AQTime from Smartbear allows you to profile both managed and unmanaged code. It's not as easy to use as ANTS, but there's more information available. See http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/application-performance-profiling