# Java thread creation performance vs C# thread creation performance vs C++ (native threads)?

Tags: c#, java, c++, multithreading, performance

I'm interesting what are actual costs of threads creation in Java, C# and C++? I know that when thread is creating a bunch of operations must be done: allocate thread stack, initialize descriptors, etc.

But I'm interesting in actual costs. C# and Java use different VM's and different JITs and C++ executes native code. So thread creation time is different in all of these languages. I also heard that thread creation in Java is much slower that in C#. Can someone give authorative answers and explanations on this issue?

Comment: Generally, the authoritative answer is "if thread *creation* is a bottleneck in your application, then you are doing it wrong". You should not be creating and destroying threads so often that it makes *any* kind of difference. Use a thread pool, if you have many short-lived tasks that start and stop frequently.

Comment: @jalf: Sometimes you need to choose between doing two tasks in sequence and launching the second task as a new thread so it won't block the current thread or be blocked by the first task. You're interested in which gets the job done fastest _and_ which makes best use of the CPU. Knowing the costs of launching a new thread could help you make the decision.

Comment: Exactly jalf is right, [creating and destroying](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#mgrmem) threads are not such a good practice and you should not take care about the creation time, instead take care to [recycle a thread](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#trpool) many times

Comment: @RalphChapin please re-read my comment. I didn't say "just do everything in sequence", I said that you can run them in parallel without launching a new thread for every task. That is what thread pools are for. You get to run the tasks in parallel *without* incurring the cost of spawning a new thread.

Comment: @jalf: That is a way to do it.  But when you have a task to run, you'll end up waiting for a thread if your pool is too small or having a bunch of threads sitting idle and burning memory if it's too large.  Finding the right size for something, such as thread pool or array, is always tricky.  At any rate, if someone answers this question, I'll be interested.

Comment: "Having a bunch of threads sitting idle" does not burn memory. At worst, it burns a bit of address space. But yes, there are always tradeoffs to anything. My point is simply that if you spin up new threads so frequently that thread startup cost *matters*, then you should not do that, and instead reuse existing threads -- for example via a thread pool.

Comment: Is this not implementation specific?

Comment: Which particular JVM and CLR implementation are you interested in? And which C++ compiler, running on which OS? Believe it or not, none of the three languages' specifications contain text to the effect "creating a thread shall take between N and N+M microseconds". It is entirely up to the implementation. All of the languages you mention have multiple implementations.

Comment: While interesting, I do not think this question is specific enough for SO.

Comment: I think it is important to emphasize @jalf's answer again. Generally, the authoritative answer is "if thread creation is a bottleneck in your application, then you are doing it wrong". You should not be creating and destroying threads so often that it makes any kind of difference. Use a thread pool, if you have many short-lived tasks that start and stop frequently. – jalf
This is the real answer here, even if it is not the logical answer to the question. As measuring thread creation is difficult and much more complex than the other answer presented here, and is useless anyway.

Comment: Thread pools are just a funny way to push "creating threads" out of an (expensive?) OS call and into the application.  The purpose of a thread is to represent an independently executable unit of work.  If you decide to have a thread *pool*, then something must gather up the bits of work to be given to the pool, and hold those bits until the pool can get around to executing them.  Those bits have now become the independent "threads".  So a thread pool simply pushes the question "how long does it take to create thread" into "how long does it take to collect a work bit and give it to the pool"?

Comment: I think thread pools etc are out of scope, and this having little practical significance has little bearing on the question. But question needs more strict bounds, such as benchmark code.

Comment: @IraBaxter: I don't se how. That work would have to be done even if you executed everything sequentially. it is not overhead associated with creating threads. And you make it sound as if it would change nothing in terms of performance. It would. Creating an OS thread is a fairly heavyweight operation. Not creating an OS thread is a very lightweight operation.

Comment: @jalf:  We aren't disagreeing. The application work done by threads, of whatever kind, is unavoidable, agreed.  But that's not what I was discussing. I was discussing the overhead of talking to the thread pool.  Yes, that's supposed to a lot cheaper than creating a thread.  My point was that if you use a pool because of such belief, you should be interested in measuring the costs of using it, to demonstrate how much cheaper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is what that happens when a thread is created.**

When a new thread is created it shares its code section, data section and operating system resources like open files with other threads. But it is allocated its own stack, register set and a program counter.

***Thread Costs***

Threading has a real cost to your program (and the system) in terms of memory use and performance. Each thread requires the allocation of memory in both the kernel memory space and your program’s memory space.

The core structures needed to manage your thread and coordinate its scheduling are stored in the kernel using wired memory. Your thread’s stack space and per-thread data is stored in your program’s memory space.

> *Most of these structures are created and initialized when you first
>   create the thread—a process that can be relatively expensive because
>   of the required interactions with the kernel.*

Some of these costs are configurable, such as the amount of stack space allocated for secondary threads. The time cost for creating a thread is a rough approximation and should be used only for relative comparisons with each other. Thread creation times can vary greatly depending on processor load, the speed of the computer, and the amount of available system and program memory.

[image]

> Threads do not consume memory (aside from their stack, which is
>   constant-sized); processes consume memory. The whole point of threads
>   is that they share process state.

**Common Language Runtime** (CLR) threads have their stack space set to
(comitted by the CLR) 1MB (4MB for 64 bit code threads) per default.

In C++ it reserves 1MB for the stack (it maps its address space), but it is not necessarily allocated in the physical memory, only a smaller part of it. If the stack grows more than that a page fault is generated and more physical memory is allocated.

Java thread creation is expensive because there is a fair bit of work involved:

- A large block of memory has to be allocated and initialized for the thread stack.
- System calls need to be made to create / register the native thread with the host OS.
- Descriptors needs to be created, initialized and added to JVM internal data structures.

It is also expensive in the sense that the thread ties down resources as long as it is alive; e.g. the thread stack, any objects reachable from the stack, the JVM thread descriptors, the OS native thread descriptors.

Comment: Thanks. This a good explanation. But can you please add more details about CLR thread creation as you do it for Java?As I understood in CLR  this step: "Descriptors needs to be created, initialized and added to JVM internal data structures" doesn't require?

Comment: You are welcome and more details about the CLR are here in this link, just take a look. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121943/net-process-memory-usage-5x-clr-heap-memory

Answer (score 8):

Benchmarking the creation of 10,000 threads in C#, Java, and Visual C++:

### C#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(DoNothing);
            thread.Start();
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
    }

    static void DoNothing()
    {
        //Do Nothing
    }
}
```

Result: 1.7638042 seconds

### Java

```
public class ThreadBencher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 //Do nothing
             }
         };

         long startTime = System.nanoTime();
         for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
             Thread thread = new Thread(r);
             thread.start();
         }
         long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
         long totalTime = stopTime - startTime;
         System.out.print(totalTime);

    }

}
```

Result: 1.514557805 seconds (or 1514557805 nanoseconds)

### Visual C++

```
DWORD WINAPI DoNothing( LPVOID lpParam ) 
{
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    HANDLE ourThreadHandle = 0;
    SYSTEMTIME st1;
    SYSTEMTIME st2;
    int i;
    GetLocalTime(&st1);
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        ourThreadHandle = CreateThread( NULL, 0, DoNothing, 0, 0, NULL);
    }
    GetLocalTime(&st2);
    double dblSt1 = st1.wSecond + (st1.wMilliseconds / 1000);
    double dblSt2 = st2.wSecond + (st2.wMilliseconds / 1000);
    double result = dblSt2 - dblSt1;
    cout << st1.wSecond << "." << st1.wMilliseconds << endl;
    cout << st2.wSecond << "." << st2.wMilliseconds << endl;
}
```

Result (after manual calculation from output): 0.925 seconds

(Disclaimer: I don't know C++ very well so the C++ code is pretty patched together)

Note: This was done in a 64-bit Windows 8 environment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a very good benchmark for any of the languages, because in c# and Java you always have to account for the how (and when!) that objects are deallocated, and prevent it from affecting the result. In real life the result could be very close or very far from the results that you have presented.
You c++ sample is much more reliable as a benchmark than the other two... Because you never destroyed your threads.

Comment: @daniel.gindi Any advice on how to account for that? (Given that we're just trying to compare how the different languages perform for thread creation, not how they perform for object deallocation.)

Comment: @daniel.gindi: Deallocation is one thing, but what about warmup? There's not much code to warmup, but still, for me using Caliper it runs about twice as fast (which might be due to different hardware or not).

Comment: the way you do it they can get deallocated during the for-loop. you can try maybe to disable the garbage collector somehow, or keep references to your threads and their functions in an array. (then you could run another loop to measure the array manipulation time and subtract that)

Comment: @maaartinus Yes warmup is not a big issue here like garbage collectors and deallocation, because the thread is a native resource, but to be accurate you still need to account for that.

Comment: @daniel.gindi I used -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps (in Java) to verify that GC doesn't run during execution of the loop I posted. GC DOES run in C#, but the effect appears to be slight as when I ran an iteration of 1000 thread creations (which doesn't trigger GC) I got a time of 0.1753645 seconds.

Comment: You should also repeat the experiment more than one time, and calculate average and standard deviation to see if you can conclude anything from the results.

Comment: @BartoszKP I did repeat them a few times, and there is some variance in the time, but the pattern of C++ > Java > C# (in terms of speed) is consistent, at least in my environment.

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice You probably should include this information, as it proves that your answer makes sense. In current form it's inconclusive.

Comment: Let those threads actually do something.

Comment: @KorayTugay The reason the threads don't do anything is because we're trying to bench the creation of threads. If the threads did something, we would also be benching that action, not just thread creation.

Comment: But Java is too smart sometimes, isnt it? Are we really benchmarking like this? Į am really asking.

Comment: @KorayTugay Refusing an instruction to create a thread just because the thread doesn't do anything isn't "smart" but since you asked I re-ran the C# and Java code a few times with each thread printing a line to console. Java still averaged about 0.2 seconds faster than C#.

Comment: Your code of Java is not equivalent to C#, in C# a new delegate to method is created for each run, where else in Java you are reusing Runner on each iteration. Try Creating ThreadStart delegate outside for loop & reuse same delegate in Thread constructor and then put the results.

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice: AFAIK `System.out.println` is synchronized, so it gets pretty unclear what gets measured. Let each Thread increment an `int` instead (without synchronization you'll get garbage at the end, but who cares).

Answer (score 0):

C++ is generally a quicker language to run, although it may be a harder language to learn; therefore longer to take to understand more basic functions, and that may slow down the process of coding it when you make the application